# Convert negative results to 0 zero in SQL

Tags: sql, case

I rounded this query into 0 decimal places.

How I can turn this case statement when the result is in NEGATIVE, it will display 0.

```
ROUND((13 - (dbo.ItemVendorDetails.LeadTime / 7 + CASE ISNULL([6WeekSales].SalesQTY / 6 , 0) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE (ISNULL(ItemsStock.StockOnHand , 0) - ISNULL(SO.OpenQTY , 0) + ISNULL(PO.[Open PO's'] , 0)) / ISNULL([6WeekSales].SalesQTY / 6 , 0) END)) * ISNULL([6WeekSales].SalesQTY / 6, 0), 0)
```

Please help :(

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: So, for example, the result is -474, the expected would be 0. Since this is a a negative result.